# export ipa from react native with xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, export, ipa

I have an app written with native responses. I want to get an iPA output file, and when I do this with xcode, the file size of the iPA is lower than 4M, and actually the file can not be installed. where is the problem from?

Answer (score 0):

Try with expo

> npm install -g exp
>
> exp build:ios

Refer: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html